# Cast Integer to Boolean in Informix

Tags: sql, casting, informix

I need to design my schema in Informix such that querying a `BOOLEAN` with an `INTEGER` type will work. e.g. `SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE isavailable = ?` works if I provide either a boolean `False` or an integer `0`. I know I need to set up the schema with some kind of cast, but I'm not sure how. The reason for doing this is a bug in another part of the software I'm working with, which is not mine to fix :-(

Comment: `CAST('t' AS BOOLEAN)` and `CAST('f' AS BOOLEAN)` work in Informix 11.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Function and Cast

```
create function expcast_int_to_bool(i integer) returning boolean;
    if   (i is null) then return null;
    elif (i != 0)    then return 't';
    else                  return 'f';
    end if;
end function;

create explicit cast (integer as boolean with expcast_int_to_bool);
```

#### Demonstration

```
create table mytable
(
    id integer not null,
    isavailable boolean not null
);
insert into mytable values(1, 't');
insert into mytable values(2, 'f');

select id from mytable where isavailable = cast(0 as boolean);
select id from mytable where isavailable = cast(1 as boolean);
select id from mytable where isavailable = cast(-1 as boolean);
select id from mytable where isavailable = cast('t' as boolean);
select id from mytable where isavailable = cast('f' as boolean);
```

This demonstration can be run through DB-Access - and it correctly returns ID 2 for the first and last SELECT statements and ID 1 for the other three.  I have not formally demonstrated that it still works when the integer or boolean literals are replaced by '?'.  There is at least a moderate chance that it will work, though.

Comment: This works fine, but I would need an implicit cast (so that I don't need to call cast(? as boolean)). I'll play around with this and see how I get on.

Comment: Changing the type of cast from explicit to implicit works fine, except for when '?' is used to form statements... :-)